# Seeking easy to understand ReactJS documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I am working on my first project with ReactJS, and I need a quick lesson on some specialized fields (as I can use their docs for the basics):

1. Add and remove `<head>` items (stylesheets, JavaScript files).
2. React templates (as most of the site will have the same header and footer).
3. Best way to route and handle urls.

Any good links and documentation welcomed.

Example of what I was trying to do.

I had the following in App.js i was trying to get the `<Header />` to print before  however i ended up having to add a `<div>` around everything to get it to work and I am sure that is not the correct way to do it, I googled for 4 hours and no luck and the documentation I was looking at was very unhelpful for a beginner.

Part of App.js (full code below)

```
 render() {
            const {checked, disabled, indeterminate, status, changeEventCount} = this.state;
            return (
            <div>
            <Header />
               <main>
                <h1>MDC-Web Checkbox - React Example</h1>
                <FormField>
                  <Checkbox id="my-checkbox"
                            labelId="my-checkbox-label"
                            disabled={disabled}
                            indeterminate={indeterminate}
                            toggleChecked={this.toggleChecked.bind(this)}/>
                  <CheckboxLabel id="my-checkbox-label" for="my-checkbox">
                    The checkbox is currently {this.status()}
                  </CheckboxLabel>
                </FormField>
                <div style={{paddingTop: '12px'}}>
                  <button onClick={() => this.setState({indeterminate: true})}>Make Indeterminate</button>
                  <button onClick={() => this.setState({disabled: !disabled})}>Toggle Disabled</button>
                </div>
                <p>{changeEventCount} change events so far</p>
              </main>
              <script src='material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js'></script>
              <script>window.mdc.autoInit();</script>
                )
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.css';


export default class Header extends Component {


  render() {
    return ( 
            <header className='mdc-toolbar mdc-toolbar--fixed'>
              <div className='mdc-toolbar__row'>
                <section className='mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-start'>
                  <span className='mdc-toolbar__title'>Title</span>
                </section>
              </div>
            </header>

            );
  }
}
```

app.js

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/* eslint-disable */

import React, {PureComponent, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';
import CheckboxLabel from './CheckboxLabel';
import FormField from './FormField';

export default class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    checked: false,
    disabled: false,
    indeterminate: false,
    changeEventCount: 0
  }

  toggleChecked(evt) {
    this.setState({
      changeEventCount: this.state.changeEventCount + 1,
      checked: evt.target.checked,
      indeterminate: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {checked, disabled, indeterminate, status, changeEventCount} = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
    <Header />
       <main>
        <h1>MDC-Web Checkbox - React Example</h1>
        <FormField>
          <Checkbox id="my-checkbox"
                    labelId="my-checkbox-label"
                    disabled={disabled}
                    indeterminate={indeterminate}
                    toggleChecked={this.toggleChecked.bind(this)}/>
          <CheckboxLabel id="my-checkbox-label" for="my-checkbox">
            The checkbox is currently {this.status()}
          </CheckboxLabel>
        </FormField>
        <div style={{paddingTop: '12px'}}>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({indeterminate: true})}>Make Indeterminate</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({disabled: !disabled})}>Toggle Disabled</button>
        </div>
        <p>{changeEventCount} change events so far</p>
      </main>
      <script src='material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js'></script>
      <script>window.mdc.autoInit();</script>
        </div>
    );
  }

  status() {
    if (this.state.indeterminate) {
      return 'indeterminate';
    }
    return this.state.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
  }
}
```

index.js

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/* eslint-disable */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You've got at least four distinct questions here, and your first three are probably off-topic for being too broad or opinion-based. The actual code seems to have a distinct problem, which is on-topic, so I would recommend cutting the question down to focus on that single point.

Comment: Why don't you just take some  courses online on React? Sometimes, videos are easier to understand than text. You should try watching some great courses for React on Youtube or get a trial for a e-learning website like Treehouse, Coursera, Pluralsight, etc.

Comment: 2. For templates, you can search through the Yeoman collection. I have been using the react-static-boilerplate from kriasoft with great success. It also solves your 1. by imitation. For 3. see `react-router` docs.